# How to interact with specific area of UIButton in iOS app

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, action, area

I have to perform an action on tapping the specific area of the button. Actually on the area where only pink color is visible. Not outside of that area. Please see the attached image along with this message and let me know if I am unclear at any point.

[image]

Comment: whole button is in pink color.Which pink area are you talking about?

Comment: I think it is about analyzing image pixel and most of people miss understand it...

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass the UIButton and override it's `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` either base of the area's geometry or accessing the button's image and checking the color at a certain point.

Check out this: [OBShapedButton](http://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)

Comment: UIButton don't have this method

Comment: How will you identify whether point is within the Pink area or not? How will you calculate or find that area?

Comment: Add your last comment in the answer so that I can accept that. I can't accept your current answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom selector, and than get the touch point there. Than check if the point is inside your specific area.

```
[pinkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
//Define the area here or get the exact frame if it is already a UIView
CGRect frameOfSpecificArea = CGRectMake(10, 20, 30, 40);
- (void)buttonTouched:(UIButton *)sender withEvent:event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint tapPoint = [touch locationInView:sender];
    NSLog(@"Pink Button touched x : %f y : %f", tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y);
    BOOL pointIsInside = CGRectContainsPoint(frameOfSpecificArea, tapPoint);
    if(pointIsInside) {
       NSLog(@"Yeah, i'm a great iOS-Developer, i can check if a point is inside a CGRect!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have provided the rectangular frame. But I need to check whether user has tapped inside the pink area or not and its shape is not Ractangular

Answer (score 0):

You need create custom UIButton class and add method:

```
-(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(![super pointInside:point withEvent:event]) return NO;

    return [bezierPath containsPoint:point];
}
```

bazierPath visible area you button. Look this link [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)